# Acces a JSON api with python

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to acces data from the pokemon api and get some information from there. First you need to put in a number (only option `1` works right now). Then the pokemon name/number and the url is formed. but I get a lot of errors when

```
data = json.loads(THEURL)
print(data['forms']['name'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
#importception
import requests
import json

#import poke api
api_url = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/'

#welke database
def databaseaanvragen():
    print('Welke database wilt u aanvragen?')
    print('Hallo), wat wilt u doen?')
    print('1) Pokemons')
    print('2) Locations')
    print('3) Moves')
    keuze = input('Voer hier het nummer in: ')
    if(keuze.isdigit()):
        keuze = int(keuze)

    if keuze == 1:
        poke_naam = input('Voer de naam of het nummer van de Pokemon in: ')
        poke_value = 'pokemon/' + poke_naam
        return poke_value

#database url en data aanvragen
aangevraagd = api_url + databaseaanvragen()
data = json.loads(aangevraagd)

print(data['forms']['name'])
```

Comment: `json.loads` expects a string containing the JSON to be decoded, not a URL. `json.load` instead expects an open file pointer. In short: the `json` module will not do an actual HTTP request to get the JSON document, that's not its job; you'll need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't actually look like you are querying the JSON api with a GET request at all. You'll need code that looks something like the following:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(api_url)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
    print(error)
    sys.exit(1)
else:
   # No Exception was raised :)
   # Decode the JSON from the response content
   json_data = r.json()
```